# How can I see the list of the search results in Android emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-autocomplete

I have successfully installed the `flutter_google_places 0.3.0` package in my project and imported it into the `main.dart` file. My app runs without any issues as I have a registered API key for the Android version in Google Cloud Console and billing is enabled. However, when I enter keywords in the search input field, nothing is displayed.

```
    Prediction? p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
        context: context,
        radius: 10000000,
        types: [],
        strictbounds: true,
        mode: Mode.overlay,
        language: "en",
        components: [Component(Component.country, "US")],
        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
```

[image: Here is my output]

Is there a solution to this problem in the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the value to false.

```
strictbounds: false // change true to false
```